# Erro recuperar json no lado do php

Tags: php, javascript, json, aplicação-web

Bem, estou enviando um json para o php mas não consigo recuperar

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sys/salvar_servidor",
    datType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dados),
    success: function( data ){
        document.write(data);
    }
});
```

E no PHP

```
<?php 

$dados = $_REQUEST['dados'];

$obj = json_decode($dados);

echo  $obj->nome; 

?>
```

O problema é que o PHP me retorna um erro informando que a variável dados não é definida.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado. Poderia me informar o que estava acontecendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defina o nome do campo que enviará o json, da forma atual é ele enviado sem nome, faça

```
data: {'dados': JSON.stringify(dados)},
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou.

Comment: @Algusto, faltou definir o nome(dados) no seu ajax, antes era enviado sem nome.

Comment: Entendi. Está tudo funcionando agora =) Até mais, abarço